# Switch MySQL slave to master - BINLOG_FORMAT

Tags: mysql, database-replication, master-slave

I had a mySQL slave db that turned into master once some server migration done.
Now, when I do a mySQL restart, the db turnos on with the

```
BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT
```

So I am not able to write in the DB.

How can I move my mySQL db to be a full master db?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to enable binary log on this server by:

```
log_bin=1
BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT  / MIXED / ROWS
```

Comment: Thanks Aman, but on my other MySQL services that I have, this doesn't need to be set in the my.cnf file. Why here there is a need for that?

Comment: whats the error when you are trying to write on db ?

Comment: error=Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging.

Comment: This is because InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED.

You should change the binlog format. Check this link:
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58459/mysql-error-impossible-to-write-to-binary-log

Comment: Thanks, so I should change / comment the READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED?

Comment: you can try this otherwise change binlog format to mixed..
You can check your isolation level by this command:

SELECT @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation;